# What is upper bound for the largest prime in a counter-example for robin's inequality

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, riemann-hypothesis

What is upper bound for the largest prime in a counter-example for robin's inequality ?!

Assume that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{ n \ln \ln n} > e^\gamma$ for some $n>5040$, and let $p$ be the biggest prime dividing $n$ what is the known upper bound for $p$.

I did search in known papers and found upper bound for $SA$, $CA$ , and all these classes, but i want a **more general upper bound** not specific for an subset of numbers.

But from my search i have a pretty good guess that $p \approx \ln n$ but could not prove it ??!

Comment: in Robin (1984) he shows that, if RH is false, then there is a CA number violating the inequality; alright, infinitely many. pages 204 and 205, with RH false, the sequence of CA numbers has $$  \frac{\sigma(n)}{\log \log n} = e^\gamma \left( 1 + \Omega_{\pm} (\log n)^{-b} \right) $$ He does not mention other sequences of numbers

Comment: A very good question imho. I would be grateful if you could post a link to the papers you mentioned giving upper bounds on the largest prime factors of SA and CA numbers. Based on my limited understanding I'd hazard a guess that UpperBound(CA) < UpperBound(SA) < UpperBound(HighlyAbundants). Also that UpperBound(CA) is slightly less than log(CA). Therefore it is very likely that the Upper Bound for the remaining two classes of possible RIE exceptions is, indeed approximately log(SA)or log(HA) respectively. Your pretty good guess is spot on.