# Seeking upper bound on largest prime factor of colossally abundant numbers

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

I recently came across an older post where the OP referred to papers giving upper bounds on the size of the largest prime factor in superabundant and colossally abundant numbers. I asked for links to those papers in the comments. Am still hoping for a response, however maybe it's a good stand-alone question.

Does anyone know of results on the upper bound on the size of the largest prime factor of colossally abundant numbers? It seems that the answer will roughly be slightly less than log(n) but I'd be grateful if there's some known explicit results out there. Thanks.

**Edit**
The poster of the original question has answered this question. Thanks Ahmad! [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674383/what-is-upper-bound-for-the-largest-prime-in-a-counter-example-for-robins-inequ) is the original post.

Comment: Maybe you should edit in a link to that older post. Also, you could try calculating the largest prime factor of the first few colossally abundant numbers, and then type the sequence you get into the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: Question from same user, about superabundant numbers, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974522/what-is-the-greatest-known-lower-bound-for-logs-in-terms-of-p-where-s-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main paper i rely on in my question was "A Class of Equivalent Problems Related to the Riemann Hypothesis" by Sadegh Nazardonyavi in which in proposition 3.33 he proves that $ \sqrt{p} < \ln n -\theta(p) < \sqrt{3p}$ for large enough super abundant (SA) number $n$ and $p$ being the largest prime divisor of $n=2^k \cdots p$.

Other important papers are for Erdos, Nicolas on highly composite numbers.

Also one can show from PNT that any counter-example for RH must have these properties :

$n =2^k \cdots p$ a multiplication of primes in ascending order and the powers in descending order.

And that $\ln n \approx \theta(p) \approx p$.

I did it 2 years ago and never looked back to it, so i don't have any papers on my pc nor my own proof for the statements above but you should find them in Sadegh Nazardonyavi,Erdos works.

I tried to make them sharp as a way to attack RH, but i couldn't improve on the bounds you should get from PNT.

Comment: In all of Highly composite numbers like(SA,CA,...)  $ \ln n- p$ changes sings infinitely many often since $ \sqrt{3p}>\ln n- \theta(p) > \sqrt{p}$ so when $ p< \theta(p) $ then its positive but according to Littlewood $ \theta(p)-p <- \sqrt{p } \ln \ln \ln p$ infinitely many often and so $ \ln n-p <0$, I am glad the paper helped you, search for Erdos paper (its a master piece).

Comment: Yes Ahmad very enlightening. Thank you, and I'll definitely check out Erdos

Answer (score 2):

The largest possible factor of a number will be $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\space\rfloor$ but these numbers have many factors by definition so the largest factor will be much less and one might think it would be the $x^{th}$ root of the number where x is the number of digits but this proves to be far too aggressive with larger values of n.

Your conjecture appears correct. For instance, the largest prime factor of $224403121196654400$ is $37$ and
log $224403121196654400\approx 40.$ A discussion of this and other 'abundant numbers is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number).